# How to change PIN using SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I created an App which has a 4 digit PIN Number to Login. I saved that in a String varaible like `String defaultPin="1234";`. I gave an option in `OptionsMenu` to change PIN. If we click Change PIN it will prompt a `Dialog` with three `EditText` boxes to get Old PIN, New PIN and Re-Enter PIN and a `Button` to save it. It works fine PIN changes. But if I restart the App again the new PIN is not working. Default PIN works.
My Code is

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String defaultPin="1234";
EditText etOldPin,etNewPin,etRePin;
Button btnCPin;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etPin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final ImageButton btnTest=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etPin.getText().toString().equals(defaultPin)){

                Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error! Check PIN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.changePin:
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Change Pin Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showDialogPin();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void showDialogPin() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_pin, null);
    alertBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    AlertDialog alertDialog=alertBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    etOldPin=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    etNewPin=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    etRePin=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    btnCPin=(Button)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button);

    btnCPin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strOldPin=etOldPin.getText().toString();
            String strNewPin=etNewPin.getText().toString();
            String strRePin=etRePin.getText().toString();

            if (strOldPin.equals("") || strNewPin.equals("") || strRePin.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All Fields must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (strOldPin.equals(defaultPin)) {
                    if (strNewPin.equals(strRePin)) {
                        defaultPin = strNewPin;
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "PIN Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "PIN's Mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter exact Old PIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`}`

This is my code.
Screenshot is
[image]

Please Help me...

Edited with `SharedPreference`

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText etOldPin,etNewPin,etRePin;
Button btnCPin;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etPin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final ImageButton btnTest=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    final SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("account",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor=preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("pin","1234");
    editor.commit();
    editor.clear();


    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etPin.getText().toString().equals(preferences.getString("pin",""))) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Check PIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.changePin:
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Change Pin Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showDialogPin();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void showDialogPin() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_pin, null);
    alertBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    AlertDialog alertDialog=alertBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.show();
    etOldPin=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    etNewPin=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    etRePin=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    btnCPin=(Button)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button);

    btnCPin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strOldPin=etOldPin.getText().toString();
            String strNewPin=etNewPin.getText().toString();
            String strRePin=etRePin.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("account",MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor=preferences.edit();
            String storedPin=preferences.getString("pin","");
            if (strOldPin.equals("") || strNewPin.equals("") || strRePin.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All Fields must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (strOldPin.equals(storedPin)) {
                    if (strNewPin.equals(strRePin)) {
                       editor.putString("pin",strNewPin);
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.clear();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "PIN Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "PIN's Mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter exact Old PIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it do not work after restarting app is that Shared preference is not updated with new pin.

You need to update the shared preference with the new pin in `btnCPin  click listener`

For updating shared preference look into
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: ok i stored my default pin in `SharedPreference` with key "pin". Now how to update it `btnCPin.setOnClickListener`?

Comment: To update that pin use the same code you used for storing the pin. Just change the value with new pin in it.

Comment: now i have updated in share preference too. i pulled that file and checked pin changes. again when i restart the app again pin automatically updated to 1234 in shared preference :(

Comment: Can you update your whole code here. So that I can find where all preferences are updated

Comment: kindly check the question. now i have posted edited code in that.

Comment: The problem now is Every time activity is created it Changes pin value to 1234.

Comment: how to avoid that? help me please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80185/discussion-between-sanjay-hirani-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

To **edit** data from sharedpreference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("PIN", defaultPin.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

To **retrieve** data from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredPin = prefs.getString("PIN", null);
if (restoredPin != null) 
{
  //HERE YOU HAVE AVAILABLE YOUR PIN IN restoredPin 
}
```

More info:

[Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[Example 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

[Example 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#preferences)